# Compiler error in Overleaf when not in main

Tags: compiling, overleaf

Everytime when I compile my Overleaf project, I get a compiling error. The error is only caused in one of my files (which I import in my main file). In the error it states, that I don't have a \begin{document} command (which I have).
The weird thing is, that when I change into my file, where I import all the sections and I put my cursor somewhere in this file, I can compile my project.

I am wondering if anyone had a similar problem and can help me with solving it.

Comment: Welcome. // Please try standing in our shoes: none of us here has got a crystal ball, so your answer rate will remain slim at best.

Comment: Ask the overleaf support. They can look at your files and so have a chance to understand what you mean.

Comment: You can set the main document in the menu.